# Eclipse RCP disable EditorReference / IEditorPart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

[image: Eclipse RCP components]

Is it possible to "disable" an EditorReference by grain out all elements and adding a watermark over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean for any existing editor in the workbench then, no, it is not possible.

You could probably do it for an editor that you write.

Comment: Yes, I want to do it for an editor that I'm writing, but I didn't found a way to do that.

Comment: You might be able to use a transparent Canvas control over the top of the editor, but I haven't seen it any code that does this. It is certainly not easy.